# What permissions should I have on a file to make it available via owncloud and readable to my local user?

Tags: unix, permissions, owncloud

Files stored in .../owncloud/data seem to be owned by www-data and in a group of the same name.

Comment: Why do you need to access to the data folder?

Comment: To be able to manipulate the files with shell scripts, for instance.